# Using the '--help' command in argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library but for whatever reason I'm having difficult printing the `-h` argument. Here is the entire source I have:

```
# df.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe assets in our library.')
parser.add_argument('--masters', nargs='?', default=None, type=int, help='Enter one or more ids.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('hi')
```

I was under the impression that entering in the `--h` flag via:

```
$ python df.py --help
```

Would **automatically** print the `help` stuff for the file using `argparse` but I seem to be making false assumptions. It seems like I also have to add in something like this into my code?

```
if '--help' in sys.argv: print (parser.parse_args(['-h']))
```

What is the 'proper' way to print out the help args when using the `argparse` library?

Comment: as I tried them all (argparse, docopt, fire) I just can say - use click, its the best, and dump argparse

Comment: @bitranox why do you say that? Want to add an answer to address that?

Comment: i just stmbled across Your question - my 50 cents is, You might try ´click´ instead of argparse - it is just so much better and cleaner, especially for grouped commands, input from stdin, etc ... 
Therefore it is just a comment, not an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually *parse* the arguments; if you put `parser.parse_args()` in after defining the parser, it would respond to `-h`/`--help`. Typically, you'd do something like:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

so that the `args` object can be used to access the parsed argument data.

I'll also note that the argument parsing should almost certainly be controlled by the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard; if you're not being invoked as the main script, parsing the command line is unusual, to say the least. Idiomatic code would look something like:

```
# df.py
def main():
    import argparse  # Could be moved to top level, but given it's only used
                     # in main, it's not a terrible idea to import in main
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe assets in our library.')
    parser.add_argument('--masters', nargs='?', type=int, help='Enter one or more ids.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print ('hi')

    # Do something with args.masters or whatever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```